# how to access members of structures through an array of pointers to those structures

Tags: c

i am working on a simple ' Phone index ' project.
my project is made out of : structures, arrays, pointers

if've :

a structure to define persons in the index :

and three functions to create users, add them to index, display the index :

Here is my code :

```
// This is my structure definition

typedef struct
{
    char fname[30];
    char lname[30];
    char phnum[14];

} PERS;

// Function prototypes

PERS *  add_person(void);
PERS ** add_index(int );
void    show_index(PERS **, int );

// Function implementation

PERS * add_person(void)
{
    PERS * p = (PERS *) calloc(1,sizeof(PERS)); // Dynamic allocation.
    printf("    First name   : ");
    scanf("%s", p->fname);
    printf("    Last name    : ");
    scanf("%s", p->lname);
    printf("    Phone number : ");
    scanf("%s", p->phnum);

    return p;   // return a pointer to the structure PERS
}


PERS ** add_index(int nbr)
{
    int i = 0;
    PERS * r[nbr];  // an array of pointers to PERS structures.

    while(i < nbr)
    {
        r[i] =  add_person();  // populate the array with pointers to PERS
        i++;
        printf("\n");
    }

    return r;   // return the array
}


void show_index(PERS **rep, int nbr)   // recieve the array
{
    int i = 0;

    while(i < nbr)
    {   // display its content
        printf("\n");
        printf("    %s \n", rep[i]->fname);
        printf("    %s \n", rep[i]->lname);
        printf("    %s \n", rep[i]->phnum);
        i++;
    }
}
```

and of course the main program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "funcs.h"

int main()
{
    PERS ** rep =  add_index(3);   // Create an index with three items 

    printf("\n\n");

    show_index(rep,3);

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This is my input :

```
First name   : friend
Last name    : name
Phone number : 4567234512
```

This is the error i get :

```
(null)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

i've tried several solution but it's not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local array in `add_index()`: `r` is local so `return r;` makes it go out of scope. Using the pointer it yields is undefined behavior. You will also need dynamic memory allocation for that. By the way, your approach of getting user input is very dangerous. Don't use `scanf()`; always prefer `fgets()` instead (it makes easier to avoid buffer overflow errors).

Answer (score 1):

You know what !! you can solve your issue by changing just a single line.

```
PERS **r= malloc(sizeof(PERS *) * nbr);
```

Use pointer to pointer and return this value from the function..

Comment: @JohnBollinger I waited for you take a look at it :)

Comment: the storage of structures has been already reserved in ' add_person() '
and pointers to this storage is stored in an array of pointers in
' add_index() ' then, the adress of this array is returned and stored in a
double pointer in the main program.

what i want is to access those members through the pointer in the main program, so i pass it to the function ' show_array() ' wich access it like that :

index[i]->member.

Comment: i've worked aroud it and i get some results, but not what i want :

i make an index of too members and i passed the pointer to the 'show_index()' and this is what i get :

first  : 0x1aada8   = 1748392
second : 0x794fc381 = 2035270529

first:

First name  : friend1
Second name : test1
Phone number: 45

second:

First name  : friend2
Second name : test2
Phone number: 78

output:

friend1
test1
45

garbage
garbage
garbage

Comment: Thanks Mr. Gopi, it works for me. And thank you all for your help.

Comment: @c0d3r Mark is as answered if it did